# Date arithmetic on values of type DATE without resulting in TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

Let's say I am doing similar query (where `due_date` is of type `date`) :

```
SELECT
       (due_date + (7 * INTERVAL '1 DAY')) AS due_date_mod
FROM test_table
```

The resulting `due_date_mod` is type `timestamp`.

This makes sense as the result of the operation should be one type regardless of specific values and interval can have hours/minutes/seconds.
But is there a way to add days/months/years to a date without the result being time stamp and also obviously without casting? Or is casting the only way?

I know I can add days by using:

```
SELECT
       (due_date + INTEGER '7') AS due_date_mod
```

And the result is type `date`.
But can I do something similar for months or years (without converting them to days)?

EDIT:
There seems to be no solution satisfying the requirements of the question. Proper way to get the required results is in the marked answer.

Comment: Any specific reason why you don't want to cast?

Comment: @stickybit I am translating C# code into SQL and if there was a non-casting way it might make the design slightly nicer. But the question is more of a curiosity since I found the way of adding days in the second query, I was wondering if there is equivalent way for months/years (I did not find any, so if there was it would have to be something somewhat obscure, that is why I am asking here :) ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already found that you can add `integer` to `date` to add days, returning `date`:

```
SELECT due_date + 7 AS due_date_mod  -- type date
FROM   test_table;
```

(Since `date` is an integer quantity inside, it's dead simple and cheap to add `integer` to it.)

As you can see in the table [***Date/Time Operators***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#OPERATORS-DATETIME-TABLE) in the manual, there is no other operator that would return `date` (and no [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE), either).

And the unit "months" must be interpreted relative to the left operand (as months differ in their number of days). So you cannot simply extract the number of days from your months. You must use `date + interval` to get it right. Just add a cast, it's simple and very cheap:

```
SELECT (due_date + interval '3 months')::date AS due_date_mod
FROM   test_table;
```

You are aware that `(7 * interval '1 mon') = interval '7 mon'`, right?

Comment: I cannot extract days from months/years simply, but I can extract them in more complicated way. But obviously at that point using interval + cast would be multiple orders of magnitude easier :) That is why specifically excluded that as a solution. As for (7 * interval '1 mon') = interval '7 mon' - yes I know, just aesthetic preference. Basically I was looking for some trick/undocumented thing. Seems like there is none.

Comment: @mcc: No shortcut. I think I would know if there was one. Only (much) more complicated workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Originally I misinterpreted the question so what is below is examples (including output) of what @mcc had already discovered. I'll leave this answer here as they may be useful to others looking for examples of date, timestamp, and interval arithmetic.

Adding a `date` to an interval:

```
select '2021-08-11 12:23:00'::date + '2 months'::interval;
      ?column?       
---------------------
 2021-09-11 00:00:00
```

Or, if the field is a `timestamp` you can to cast it to `date`, but you still get a `datetime` answer:

```
select ('2021-08-11 12:23:00'::timestamp)::date + '2 years'::interval;
      ?column?       
---------------------
 2023-08-11 00:00:00
```

As the above examples show, when adding an `interval` to a `date` or `timestamp` the results is always a `timestamp`. If you require the results to be a date you can cast after adding the `interval`:

```
select ('2021-08-11 12:23:00'::timestamp + '60 days'::interval)::date;
    date    
------------
 2021-10-10
```

I've used intervals of days, months, and years to demonstrate how each time period can be added.

Comment: I would assume that `due_date` is `date`, not `timestamp`.

Comment: That wasn't my original assumption, but it may be what @mcc is using. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example would avoid this confusion.

Comment: @Kim the whole question would make no sense at all if due_date was timestamp :) , but I could have specified it, will add the info to the question

Answer (score 0):

reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-operator.html

```
SELECT
    oprname,
    p1.typname AS left_type,
    p2.typname AS right_type,
    p3.typname AS result_type,
    oprcode
FROM
    pg_operator po
    JOIN pg_type p1 ON p1.oid = po.oprleft
    JOIN pg_type p2 ON p2.oid = po.oprright
    JOIN pg_type p3 ON p3.oid = po.oprresult
WHERE
    oprname = '+'
    AND p1.typname = 'date'::name;
```

So there is a row like :

```
 oprname | left_type | right_type | result_type |     oprcode
---------+-----------+------------+-------------+------------------
 +       | date      | int4       | date        | date_pli
```

That's why `select now()::date + 1;` will work.

> But is there a way to add days/months/years to a date without the
> result being time stamp and also obviously without casting? Or is
> casting the only way?

"add days/months/years" Means:
Is there a operator that right side (or left side) is **interval** data type then the return is **date** data type.
Does it exist? we can query the catalog schema and find out.

```
SELECT
    oprname,
    p1.typname AS left_type,    --left side of a operator data type
    p2.typname AS right_type,   --right side of a operator data type
    p3.typname AS result_type,  --return data type
    oprcode
FROM
    pg_operator po
    JOIN pg_type p1 ON p1.oid = po.oprleft
    JOIN pg_type p2 ON p2.oid = po.oprright
    JOIN pg_type p3 ON p3.oid = po.oprresult
WHERE
    p1.typname = 'interval'::name
    OR p2.typname = 'interval'::name;
```

---

```
 oprname |  left_type  | right_type  | result_type |         oprcode
---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------
 +       | date        | interval    | timestamp   | date_pl_interval
 -       | date        | interval    | timestamp   | date_mi_interval
 +       | timestamptz | interval    | timestamptz | timestamptz_pl_interval
 -       | timestamptz | interval    | timestamptz | timestamptz_mi_interval
 =       | interval    | interval    | bool        | interval_eq
 <>      | interval    | interval    | bool        | interval_ne
 <       | interval    | interval    | bool        | interval_lt
 <=      | interval    | interval    | bool        | interval_le
 >       | interval    | interval    | bool        | interval_gt
 >=      | interval    | interval    | bool        | interval_ge
 +       | interval    | interval    | interval    | interval_pl
 -       | interval    | interval    | interval    | interval_mi
 *       | interval    | float8      | interval    | interval_mul
 *       | float8      | interval    | interval    | mul_d_interval
 /       | interval    | float8      | interval    | interval_div
 +       | time        | interval    | time        | time_pl_interval
 -       | time        | interval    | time        | time_mi_interval
 +       | timetz      | interval    | timetz      | timetz_pl_interval
 -       | timetz      | interval    | timetz      | timetz_mi_interval
 +       | interval    | time        | time        | interval_pl_time
 +       | timestamp   | interval    | timestamp   | timestamp_pl_interval
 -       | timestamp   | interval    | timestamp   | timestamp_mi_interval
 +       | interval    | date        | timestamp   | interval_pl_date
 +       | interval    | timetz      | timetz      | interval_pl_timetz
 +       | interval    | timestamp   | timestamp   | interval_pl_timestamp
 +       | interval    | timestamptz | timestamptz | interval_pl_timestamptz
 <->     | interval    | interval    | interval    | interval_dist
(27 rows)
```

As you can see the query column return type is {timestamp,timestamptz, bool, interval,time,timetz}. So it cannot return date.