# How to get a date interval with condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals, gaps-and-islands

How to get a continuous date interval from rows fulfilling specific condition?

I have a table of employees states with 2 types of user_position.
The interval is continuous if the next higher date_position per user_id has the **same user_id**, the **next day value** and **user_position didn't change**. The user cannot have different user positions in one day.

Have a feeling it requires several cases, window functions and tsrange, but can't quite get the right result.

I would be really grateful if you could help me.

Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ba641/1/0

The result should look like this:

| user_id | user_position | position_start | position_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01.01.2019 | 02.01.2019 |
| 1 | 2 | 03.01.2019 | 04.01.2019 |
| 1 | 1 | 05.01.2019 | 06.01.2019 |
| 2 | 1 | 01.01.2019 | 03.01.2019 |
| 2 | 2 | 04.01.2019 | 05.01.2019 |
| 2 | 2 | 08.01.2019 | 08.01.2019 |
| 2 | 2 | 10.01.2019 | 10.01.2019 |

Create/insert query for the source data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_position
(   id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id integer,
    user_position integer,
    date_position date);

INSERT INTO users_position (user_id,
                        user_position,
                        date_position)
VALUES
(1, 1, '2019-01-01'),
(1, 1, '2019-01-02'),
(1, 2, '2019-01-03'),
(1, 2, '2019-01-04'),
(1, 1, '2019-01-05'),
(1, 1, '2019-01-06'),
(2, 1, '2019-01-01'),
(2, 1, '2019-01-02'),
(2, 1, '2019-01-03'),
(2, 2, '2019-01-04'),
(2, 2, '2019-01-05'),
(2, 2, '2019-01-08'),
(2, 2, '2019-01-10');
```

Comment: Please provide a test case with `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` script. Consider adding a fiddle.

Comment: Added a query and a fiddle

Comment: Please define "next row". Is that the next higher `id` or the next higher `date_position` per `user_id`? (Generated `IDENTITY` values are not guaranteed to be in sequence under concurrent write load.)

Comment: Next row is the next higher date_position per user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT user_id, user_position
     , min(date_position) AS position_start
     , max(date_position) AS position_end
FROM  (
   SELECT user_id, user_position,date_position
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE (date_position = last_date + 1
                                  AND user_position = last_pos) IS NOT TRUE)
                   OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date_position) AS interval
   FROM (
      SELECT user_id, user_position, date_position
           , lag(date_position) OVER w AS last_date
           , lag(user_position) OVER w AS last_pos
      FROM   users_position
      WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date_position)
      ) sub1
   ) sub2
GROUP  BY user_id, user_position, interval
ORDER  BY user_id, interval;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=bb9393892ae3d35cf1ccc86e3182124c)*

Basically, this forms intervals by counting the number of disruptions in continuity. Whenever the "next" row per `user_id` is not what's expected, a new interval starts.

The `WINDOW` clause allows to specify a window frame once and use it repeatedly; no effect on performance.

`last_date + 1` works while `last_date` is type `date`. See:

- [Is there a way to do date arithmetic on values of type DATE without result being of type TIMESTAMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68741952/is-there-a-way-to-do-date-arithmetic-on-values-of-type-date-without-result-being/68742129#68742129)

Related:

- [Get start and end date time based on based on sequence of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73150635/get-start-and-end-date-time-based-on-based-on-sequence-of-rows/73165402#73165402)
- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35389/3684)

About the aggregate `FILTER`:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

Comment: Thank you, @Erwin Brandstetter. Looks nice!